# Tools for looking at transactions inside of transaction log backup file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transaction-log, log-shipping

Are there any tools (commercial or open source) for looking at the contents of a transaction log backup file?  Occasionally, get a large transaction log backup file and would like to see the contents / transactions inside the log backup to know what is backing up log shipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in yourself, you can check with `sys.fn_dump_dblog` the whole log file or log backup. Otherwise, there is a tool that I know but haven't tried [Apex Log Reader](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-log.aspx).